# blade view not updated

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am new to Laravel and react,I have some issues with JS files,I made some change in app.js(rename "Example" to "Examplee") but this is not rendering in the browser(incognito) .
I have cleared session and and config cache ,I deleted views cache too but didn't help.

```sh
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01:/var/www/html/laratweet/resources/js# more app.js
```

First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 includes React and other helpers. It's a great starting point while
 building robust, powerful web applications using React + Laravel.

```php
require('./bootstrap');
```

Next, we will create a fresh React component instance and attach it to
 the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.

```php
 require('./components/Examplee');
```

Any idea why the JS update is not updated in the browser?

```sh
php artisan --version
```

Laravel Framework 6.14.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile the changes when up update your `resources` files.

`npm run dev`

See: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix for full details on other commands.

Comment: thanks a lot,that's solve my issue ,is it something we can do in production too?

Comment: There is an `npm run production` process that compiles, minifies, etc. It's a pretty robust system, I recommend reading the document fully.